# How to add custom styling to custom Button in TinyMCE ( Version >4) in Vue2

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

I'm using @tinymce/tinymce-vue in my Vue application. I have added a custom button which will be appear on selecting the text. I want to give it some custom styling , but the problem is that I can't give class to this button and global stylling applies to other buttons also. Giving `classes` key in setup object doesn't work for TinyMCE version above 4. Can anyone please provide any solution to this.

Editor Setup :-

```
editorSetup(editor) {
        new ReferenceVariableAutocompleter(editor, tinymce, this.getDropdownData.bind(this));        editor.ui.registry.addIcon(
          'CustomIcon',
          '<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M16.082 6.77083L15.1862 4.6875L13.0195 3.72917L15.1862 2.79167L16.082 0.8125L16.9779 2.79167L19.1445 3.72917L16.9779 4.6875L16.082 6.77083ZM16.082 19.1667L15.1862 17.1667L13.0195 16.2292L15.1862 15.2917L16.082 13.1875L16.9779 15.2917L19.1445 16.2292L16.9779 17.1667L16" fill="#ffff"/></svg>'
        );
        editor.ui.registry.addButton('CustomButton', {
          icon: 'CustomIcon',
          classes: 'custombtn',
          onAction: () => {
            this.selectedText = editor.selection?.getContent({ format: 'raw' });
            editor.focus();
            this.showPopOver();
          },
        });
      },
    },
```

I tried to apply classes , but it does not apply to this button. Also tried giving global styling , but it added to other buttons, which I does not want.